# Biztalk Orchestrations Managing BRE Failures

Tags: error-handling, biztalk, biztalk-rule-engine

I have been having trouble managing Orchestrations and Business Rule Engines.  I wish to capture, in my orchestration, a BRE failure so that if a BRE failure occurs I chose an alternate routing pattern.  My orchestration in port is an MX receiving pipeline.  From research I have been able to find the SWIFTErrorExtractor.ErrorExtractor but for some reason although my messages are failing with 6 BRE validation rules, my orchestration fails with an exception being unable to extract an error segment from my message.

The only way I was able to find the BRE failures was to enlist but not start my orchestration and enable my ports.  Place the message in the "in" folder.  Then from the main page, search for all suspended messages, and this message has the errors.

How can I capture these error descriptions?

Comment: Couple of questions: 1. Is the BRE validation occuring in the pipeline? 2. If the validations fails, is the incoming message altered  in the pipeline?

Comment: The BRE Validation occurs in the pipeline.  Currently there is no further validation in the pipeline.  Since your question is asking this, I am currently looking into a custom pipeline validation.  If the pipeline has BRE failures, should it not automatically add these error's to the message?  And if so, how do I extract or determin if BRE validation error's occured?

Comment: Did you try creating a send port (for testing purpose) or another orchestration and subscribe to this promoted property **A4SWIFT_Failed==True**? The documentation states : ** _A body part containing the failed message

An error part containing the error-collection XML

Promoted properties indicating the failure state_ **

Comment: Yes I did.  The message did get placed in the error folder I created but no error was attached to the message that I could see.  I did find a way that my orchestration can see if a BRE validation error occured by using the following - painMSG(Microsoft.Solutions.MX_A4SWIFT.Property.MX_A4SWIFT_BreValidationErrors);  This returns the number of bre validation errors I am receiving but I am not able thus far to extract the errors from the message.

Comment: In your test send port, which subscribes to the **A4SWIFT_Failed==True**, stop it, try your error scenario. This will create a suspended message in Biztalk for that send port. Examine its context properties and also the message.

Comment: I followed your instructions and was able to see the error part.  I was able to find this earlier by turning on the receive ports to my orchestration and stopping the orchestration.  It would do the same thing of creating a suspended message.  My issue here though is that I want to be able to capture these errors in the orchestration so that I can inform the authors via email of the errors in their file.  When I try to access the error segment of the files that have BRE validation errors, it throws an exception stating that the segment does not exist.  Is there a way, from the orchestration?

Comment: Please review my solution to see if this makes any sense.  Instead of implementing my message directly I implemented a multi part message.  With the "Body" part being my message and the "Error" part being an XML document.  When running my orchestration the "Error" part was automatically filled in with the validation errors.  I was unable to find this any where online and got the solution staring at the suspended message in my BizTalk Admin Console.  It had 2 parts a Body and Error.  So I created the same multi part msg and it worked.  I seriously doubted that would work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, that's the only way to implement it as its a multipart message. I am glad you could finally resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing my message directly I implemented a multi part message. With the "Body" part being my message and the "Error" part being an XML document. When running my orchestration the "Error" part was automatically filled in with the validation errors. I was unable to find this any where online and got the solution staring at the suspended message in my BizTalk Admin Console. It had 2 parts a Body and Error. So I created the same multi part msg and it worked. I seriously doubted that would work.